# gRPC proxied through pfSense with HAProxy plugin

Tags: haproxy, pfsense, grpc

I am trying to make a **gRPC** server available through **pfSense** with **HAProxy** running as a **plugin**.
I have ssl termination at HAProxy and it works fine for a number of hosts.
But trying to set the gRPC server it fails with:

**Bad gRPC response. HTTP status code: 400**

However I can succesfully do that using **Nginx Proxy Manager** by setting the following in **Custom Nginx Configuration**:

```
underscores_in_headers on;
location / {
    grpc_read_timeout 300s;
    grpc_send_timeout 300s;
    grpc_socket_keepalive on;
    if ($http_content_type = "application/grpc") {
        grpc_pass grpc://10.0.0.5:6000;
    }
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    # Proxy!
    include conf.d/include/proxy.conf;
}
```

Comment: A small progress I made:   
In **Frontend** I have checked **SSL Offloading** and in the **Advanced certificate specific ssl options** I have **alpn h2,http/1.1**  
In the associated Backend, in **Advanced settings** in **Per server pass thru** I have **proto h2**  
It still doesn't work, but now the error is: **The HTTP/2 server reset the stream. HTTP/2 error code 'REFUSED_STREAM' (0x7)**